# If $L_1$ is perpendicular to line $K$, and $L_2$ is also perpendicular to line $K$, then $L_1$ is parallel to $L_2$.

Tags: geometry, logic, first-order-logic, alternative-proof, natural-deduction

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 49)

> **Theorem 1-2**. If $L_1$ is perpendicular to line $K$, and $L_2$ is also perpendicular to line $K$, then $L_1$ is parallel to $L_2$.

[image]

I will assume that $L_1 \nparallel L_2$, and then use

> **PERP 1**. Given a line $L$ and a point $P$, there is one and only one line through $P$, perpendicular to $L$.

to reach a contradiction.

$L_1 \nparallel L_2$ means
$$
L_1 \neq L_2 \land \exists P(P \in L_1 \land P \in L_2)
$$

**Proof of Theorem 1-2:**

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\oi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor I} \: #1 \\}
\def\oe#1{\qquad\mathbf{\lor E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

$
\fitch{1.\,L_1 \perp K\\
2.\,L_2 \perp K\\
3.\,\forall u\forall P\exists!l(P \in l \land l \perp K) \qquad \text{[PERP 1]}
}{
 4.\,\exists!l(P \in l \land l \perp K)\\
 \fitch{5.\,L_1 \nparallel L_2}{
    6.\,L_1 \neq L_2 \land \exists P(P \in L_1 \land P \in L_2)\\
    7.\,L_1 \neq L_2\\
    8.\,\exists P(P \in L_1 \land P \in L_2)\\
    \fitch{9.\,P \in L_1 \land P \in L_2}{
     \fitch{10.\,P \in Z \land Z \perp K \land \forall l'(P \in l' \land l' \perp K \to l' = Z)}{
       11.\,\forall l'(P \in l' \land l' \perp K \to l' = Z)\\
       12.\,P \in L_1 \land L_1 \perp K \to L_1 = Z\\
       13.\,P \in L_2 \land L_1 \perp K \to L_2 = Z\\
       14.\,L_1 = L_2
}\\
15.\,L_1 = L_2
}\\
16.\,L_1 = L_2\\
17.\,\bot
}\\
18.\,L_1 \parallel L_2
}
$

Is this a good proof skeleton ? Am I heading in the right direction ?

P.D.: rules of inference can be found in Appendix C of this book: http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/forallxyyc.pdf

Comment: What is the space in which you are working? This result is true in two dimensions but false in three  or mote dimensions.

Comment: Thank you. I will edit the question and add the image. I am working in two dimensions.

Comment: The three axes in 3D-space are mutually perpendicular. It is also possible for a line in 3D-space to be perpendicular to two skew lines.

Comment: Suppose $L_1$ and $L_2$ intersect, then you have a triangle with angle sum greater than $\pi$. $\Box$

Comment: @astro, I do not think I can use it at this stage of the book. Nevertheless, I am wondering, why their angle sum would be greater than $\pi$ ?

Comment: Because they already sum up to $\pi$ with the ones coming from perpendicular lines.